# Redis + Soulmate on heroku - Implementing autocomplete on multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, autocomplete, redis

This is my first experience with redis, I am implementing autocomplete on the search form with  [soulmate](https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate) and redis.

I have installed redis on my local machine and I have to do redis-server to make sure redis is working.

To make it work on heroku I have used [redis_to_go](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo/) and followed the instruction given on the link.

However it seems redis server is not getting started as I keep getting the error `Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)`.

I have created a redis.rb file in initializer which has the following code :-

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] ||= "redis://redistogo:972612d8048aad8@tarpon.redistogo.com:9436/"

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

I am expecting this piece of code to start redis server for me.

What else do I need to do to make redis work on heroku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head for 2 days I think implementing autocomplete with rails is a poor option in production.

I was able to implement it on my development machine but redis + heroku was a nightmare for me and very poor support by the redis_to_go team.

I have implemented autocomplete search using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this after going back and forth with Redis Cloud support.

I needed to make a file - config/initializers/soulmate.rb:

```
Soulmate.redis = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Although you've moved on, to answer the original question: I found a discussion about this in the Soulmate issues list: https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate/pull/20 (extra info: the fix was merged into the gem well before this question was posed).

So, to solve the problem: add 'ENV["REDIS_URL"] = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]' to redis.rb.
My own redis.rb now looks like this:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
ENV["REDIS_URL"] = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]
```